# Python datetime precision

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine datetime property which I populate with `x.date = datetime.datetime.now()`. I do a lot of comparisons between dates, and after much debugging, it turns out my client device sends dates out with less precision than a Python date, which caused a terrible mess.

Here is what Python generates:
`2012-08-28 21:36:13.158497` with `datetime.datetime.now()`, but what I want is `2012-08-28 21:36:13.158000` (notice the three zeros at the end.)

How can I achieve this? (keep in mind, I'm *not* trying to format strings or anything. I want to format a date object.)

I guess one way would be to format it into a string with desired precision, like this:

```
dateString = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

and then back to a date object. But there's got to be a better way.

Comment: even if the client has better precision aren't you going to have problems with clock skew between client and server and different server instances.

Comment: If you have a bug caused by your client and server not being synchronized with nanosecond accuracy, you're not going to fix it on a networked system at all. Network latency is going to be orders of magnitude bigger than that rounding error.

Comment: Why are you doing equality comparisons on a datetime in the first place? This is as bad as doing equality comparisons on a float.

Comment: @NickJohnson well the user connects every time to get new data since the last time he got new data. So I do a query kind of like "get new entities with create date newer than last sync date". Is this bad?

Comment: @mohabitar In which case you'd be doing an inequality query on the date, right? So why are you trying to truncate the datetime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dt = dt.replace(microsecond = (dt.microsecond // 1000) * 1000)
```

This will truncate the last 3 digits. Proper rounding is a little more complicated due to the possibility that it might round to 1000000 microseconds.

Comment: int(round(dt.microsecond, -3)) looks more clear for me, but doesn't really make difference

Comment: @Marat, as I explained you can't use `round` without complicating the solution quite a bit.

Comment: dt = dt.replace(microsecond = int(dt.microsecond / 1000) * 1000)

Comment: @mparkes when I wrote this answer Python 2.7 was still quite popular and the division would have produced an int anyway.  I'll replace it with a truncating division.